# What can cause incorrect user names when using IIS & Windows Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, iis

I'm currently experiencing an issue with *some* users of an ASP.NET 4.8 Web API application hosted on Windows Server 2012 and IIS. The following properties are not returning that user's correct user name, and instead returning the name of a service account used for this server:

- `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`

I have no idea how to begin troubleshooting this - myself and most other users do not experience this issue, but for a handful of users the above does not return the correct username, returning the username of a service account used to remotely connect to the server in question. Forcing a login via a browser private window does rectify the issue, and the application correctly returns the expected username for each of the above properties.

What could be a cause for Windows Authentication not returning the correct user name and what is the best way to troubleshoot an issue like this?

**edit: I was able to resolve the issue, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66247490/1404170) below**

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/miseries-around-asp-net-windows-authentication-setup-14e2e8522ad2

Comment: I believe it'll use an http-only cookie for login details. (To tie browser session to domain login.)  It sounds like this service account was used on these people's machines to login and they've got saved cookies from that session.

Comment: So once they delete that cookie, when they go to the site it'll prompt them for their domain login.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks - I did not see an HttpOnly cookie on these users' machines, and even after clearing all cookies and other data, the issue seems to persist. I mentioned in another comment below that I have opened a support ticket with MS, and I will update here with what their findings and/or solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some additional research and troubleshooting, I determined that the users experiencing the issue described above had the service account in question stored in the Windows Credential Manager:

[image]

Removing the service account in question allowed them to be authenticated with the Intranet site with their normal Windows domain\username. As @pcalkins suggested, at some point the affected users had used these credentials on their machine, and Chrome, Edge, IE were using that saved credential when authenticating with the Intranet site.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following steps:

1. Make sure that windows authentication is enable and Anonymous Authentication is disable for the website.
2. Enable integrated security in Interner Explorer (Options/Advanced and checkin the "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" option).
3. Add your website to Local Intranet zone and select at least "Automatic logon only in Intranet Zone" option under Options/Security Settings/Local intranet/Custom level).
4. Aake sure the user and application server are in the same domain.

Comment: Thanks for this. The site and application in IIS both have Anonymous Authentication disabled and Windows Authentication enabled. Users are not typically using Internet Explorer, but I verified with a user that "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" was checked and the site was added to the Local Intranet Zone with "Automatic logon.." option set but the issue still persists. The user and app server are on the same domain. I am opening a support ticket with MS on this, and I will update here with my findings and/or solution.